# react state hook wont update on sort even making a copy of the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so i am using a onClick even o a li.

this is the function:

```
const filterByName = () => {
        const copiedData = [...data];

        const sort = copiedData.sort((a: any, b: any) => a.fullName > b.fullName && b);
        setData(sort);
    }
```

if i log, the log displays correctly, but even making a copy of the `data` it wont cause the dom to rerender when i call setData.

`data` is an array of objects.

any tip?

Answer (score 2):

This is possibly caused by unique per-item `key` props not being rendered into your list, which is [typically required to reliably sort/update rendered lists](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Ensure that you specify a `key` prop on each `li` element as shown:

```
<ul>
   { data.map((item) => (
   <li key={item.thisItemsUniqueId}> {/* <-- add unique key, per item */}
   Your per-list item display
   </li>)) }
</ul>
```

Also, update your `sort` callback to return a positive or negative number to correctly sort the resulting array, rather than a "boolean" result [as detailed here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description):

```
const sort = copiedData.sort(
    (a: any, b: any) => (a.fullName > b.fullName && b) ? 1 : -1
    );
```